# Can we have multiple doctypes for one index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was going through the [elasticsearch guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) and I wanted to know whether it's a good practice to have multiple doctypes for one index.

Eg. In [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html), there's a twitter index with a doctype of _doc. Now if I create another doctype (say tweet) on the same index having a different mapping, is it going to affect the performance in any way ?

I found this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725618/should-create-multiple-document-types-or-multiple-indexes) but it doesn't adequately answers my doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to have more than 1 mapping type per index but starting from ES 6 and onwards, the mapping types will be removed. So I would definitely not advice to use it.

See the [Schedule for removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types).